# Use CopyFileEx to copy encrypted file of another user

Tags: c#, .net

I want to copy some encrypted files of other user from one computer to another using CopyFileEx API in c#.

CopyFileEx decrypts file before copy to target. Files can be decrypted by the only user who encrypted them.

In this case, I will get error message of Access Denied.

Is there a way using CopyFileEx to achieve this?

Comment: Is the destination encrypted too? By the current user?

Comment: I need to copy it encrypted on destination too. It will like backup of file.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that to access encrypted file content you should be authorized as specific user. That is the purpose of encryption.

If your task is backup only, you can use [ReadEncryptedFileRaw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365466(v=vs.85).asp) and [WriteEncryptedFileRaw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365746(v=vs.85).aspx) pair to backup/restore encrypted files without actually decrypting it.

But if still want to access file encrypted by another user and you have his credentials, you can use [impersonation](https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation).